# Arithmetic comparison in Prolog

Tags: prolog, arithmetic-expressions

Let's say we have two variables `X` and `Y`. `X` is `53` and `Y` is `52`. What I want to do is compare them by adding `1` to the `Y`, so that it would be `53` - therefore `X` would be equal to `Y + 1`.

I am trying to do it by simply using equal operator and addition for `Y` variables, like so:

```
X == Y + 1
```

Even though this looks simple enough, I am getting `false` as the result. What am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure the variables are grounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
?- X = 50+2, Y = 50+1, X =:= Y + 1.
```

as you can see, ([=:=](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28%3D:%3D%29/2))/2 evaluates both sides, as do (>)/2, etc

Answer (score 1):

If you are reasoning over integers, use your Prolog system's **CLP(FD) constraints** to compare and evaluate arithmetic integer expressions.

For example, in SICStus, SWI and YAP, after `use_module(library(clpfd)`:

```
?- 53 #= 52 + 1. 
true.
```

This works in all directions.

Other examples:

```
?- X #= 52 + 1.
X = 53.

?- 53 #= Y + 1.
Y = 52.

?- 53 #= 52 + 1.
true.
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to evaluate expression trees, the [`is`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=is/2) predicate is used:

```
X is Y+1.
```

you must be careful however, this will only work as a *test* if both `X` and `Y` are grounded. And will always error if variables on the right hand side (`Y` in this case) is not grounded.

**`swipl` demo**:

```
?- X = 53, Y = 52, X is Y+1.
X = 53,
Y = 52.

?- X = 53, Y = 52, X is Y.
false.
?- X = 53, X is Y+1.
ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
?- Y = 52, X is Y+1.
Y = 52,
X = 53.
```